# Template in variant does not read Arabic version

Tags: sxa

I used Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8, I created variant and inserted new template when i added Arabic version for template.
[image]
I see that template does not read Arabic version and read English version only. 
[image]

any idea what the reason of this issue ??

Comment: You have abused the Variant template. :(

Comment: That is not something you should be doing. Variant Template is like last resort. When you can't achieve something with Variant Field, and for example Variant Section you can use Variant Template and for example generate fancy link wrapped with something custom. But not half HTML of the page:D What you did is completely not manageable!